# using an email intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-file

Okay, I've been going over this for a while, and I'm not getting it.  none of the suggestions in multiple links has solved the problem.

I have successfully set up my Application to send files.  currently, I am trying to work on opening those files with my application.

My activity opens when I click on the file in the received email.

What I need it to do next is to save the file locally, in a the external storage folder that my application uses.

So, when you click on a file and the intent filter opens the correct activity, what do you do next to access that file?

intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.gmgt" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Activity:

```
public class ActFileReceiver extends Activity {

private TextView label;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_file_receiver);

    label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblFileRecieverText);


}
```

}

intent used to send file:

```
public void emailFile(File file) {
    Uri fileURI = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent mailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    mailIntent.setType("messsage/vnd.com.boardmonkey.TABLETop.gamefile");
    mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "TABLETop game file: " + file.getName());
    mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileURI);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mailIntent, "Send Mail With..."));
}
```

Comment: "I don't have a code sample" -- sure you do. You have an activity and you have an `<intent-filter>`, according to your question. The details of what to do vary by what your `<intent-filter>` is for (`ACTION_VIEW`? `ACTION_SEND`? something else?). So, give us that, at least.

Comment: fair enough, wasn't thinking that deep, my bad.  edited to reflect what I actually do have.

Comment: the action_sendto works just fine, my application will successfully send the files through any send capable application on the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking to support `ACTION_VIEW`. If you look at [the documentation for `ACTION_VIEW`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW), you will find:

> Input: getData() is URI from which to retrieve data.

Here, "input" is referring to the data sent from whoever called `startActivity()` to you, the one with the activity that the user chose. And, methods referenced in `Intent` action documentation refer to the `Intent` itself.

So, call `getIntent()` to retrieve the `Intent` that was used to create your activity, and call `getData()` on it to get a `Uri` to the content that you are supposed to view.

---

Now you start running into problems, though. Specifically, you are trying to use `android:pathPattern`. Your use has two issues:

1. [You cannot use `android:pathPattern` without also specifying `android:scheme` and `android:host`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html#path).
2. It's 2017, and few things use file extensions anymore. In particular, most content is shared via `Uri` values with `content` schemes, and a `content` `Uri` is unlikely to have a file extension.

The only semi-effective way to use `android:pathPattern` is to limit yourself to the `file` scheme (via `android:scheme`), then live with the fact that your app will interoperate with a steadily decreasing number of apps over time.

Comment: okay, this is what I was missing!!  my app doesn't have to interoperate with other apps, it's a suite set that only needs to share files with itself, output files such as text or sms documents will be formatted separately in their own intents, i.e. if a file's name is to be shared via facebook the name will be pulled into a string from the file and sent as text.

so, scheme and host: my file is a serialized file from an object my app creates, so that means it's just scheme:file?

and I'll look up "host", but I assume that is the source of the file, like email or web, right?

Comment: @JohnHaines: "my app doesn't have to interoperate with other apps" -- yes, it does. At the moment, your app is advertising that *any* app can ask it to view content. If that is not what you want, you are going to need to take a different approach.

Comment: any app can view the files. they just can't do anything with them, because they are serialized objects.  if someone wants to write an app that interprets that object, that doesn't bother me.  I just want my app to save the file locally.

Comment: and I understand what you are saying, but honestly that's a step I'm not currently working on.

Comment: @JohnHaines: With regards to what the scheme and host are, they need to match what it is that your other app is using with the `Uri` it is putting in the `Intent` for `startActivity()` that is triggering this activity. If you do not care about interoperability, all that matters is that the two apps agree on what the `Uri` structure means.

Comment: dude, I just looked at your background, and I think what I really need is a training session on the subject.  I'm going to look into CommonsWare and if I can come up with the resources I'll hit you up there!

Comment: so, if I use scheme:file in the action_send, the reciever needs to look for scheme:file, that part I got.  I'm still not really getting what "host" is, but I'm looking around at other questions right now.

my main problem is what do do with the Uri I get from getData().

Comment: where I'm at:  if I download the file on my device, and manually move it into the folder the app uses for files, my app will open it.

I don't need the receiver to open the file.  I just need it to move that file into the app's file folder.

Comment: @JohnHaines: For a `file` scheme, there is no host. AFAIK, your `<intent-filter>` would use `android:host="*"`, and your other app would not worry about it. The host matters more for `http`, `https`, and `content` schemes.

Comment: okay, getting this.  doing a String from uri.getPath on that getData() Uri, to see what it's actually telling me I've received.  this is starting to line up a bit.

thank you so much for sticking through this with me, I'm 5,000 lines of code in and getting stuck here was starting to freak me out.

Comment: going to upvote this answer, the information along with the discussion makes me feel like you've got me on the right path.

Comment: MAN, I JUST GOT IT!! YOU ROCK!!